# Debian 10 not detecting second monitor

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I'm having a hard time detecting my second monitor on debian 10: One is connected through my NVIDIA graphics card, is detected and works perfectly. The other screen is connected through my intel integrated graphics card, and does not show at all on my configuration, no matter what i try. I've enabled multiscreen on my BIOS, tried to switch both cables and screens to verify the hardware, both screens (and related cables) are working.

The output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aeb (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aec (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aed (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
04:01.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

lspci -nn | grep VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Rev. A] [10de:2182] (rev a1)
```

I couldnt find any case where the second monitor doesnt even show up in LSPCI. I'm guessing something is missing related to my integrated graphical card but i have no idea what...

Here is what lspci -v | less got me :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-9th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: de000000-df0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d20fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 530
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at dd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at df331000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at df310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at df330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at df32f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at df32e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at df32d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at df328000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at df32c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at df32b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: df200000-df2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: df100000-df1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at df324000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
    Memory at df320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at df32a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Rev. A]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3fbe
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at df080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3fbe
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at d2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at d2040000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3fbe
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at df084000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
    Memory behind bridge: df200000-df2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>

04:01.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Compex Wireless 802.11 b/g  MiniPCI Adapter, Rev A1 [WLM54G]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 19
    Memory at df200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
    Kernel modules: ath5k

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `xrandr --listproviders` say?

Comment: Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x1b9 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 7 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0

Comment: Your X server is only using the Nvidia GPU, probably because the default configuration for the proprietary Nvidia driver assumes only one GPU. First you’ll need to get that command to register both GPUs, and then ”xrandr —setprovideroutputsource 1 0”  should allow the Nvidia GPU to pass its output also through the other GPU’s outputs. At that point the displays connected to the other GPU will become accessible for extending/cloning the desktop. (More later when I’m not on the mobile.)

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, my native GPU is somehow not recognised by my computer, either because it is deactivated or because i didnt install the right intel drivers? I dont see what else could block it to the point where it doesent even appear in the provider list output?

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Nvidia proprietary driver, you should have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf` file (or possibly `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file) that tells the X11 server to use the proprietary driver - unfortunately by default, the X11 server takes it to mean it should use that driver **only**.

You would have to add a second `Section "Device"` block into it, specifying the Intel driver too.

The Device section might look like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "IntegratedIntel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:00:02.0"
EndSection
```

And you might also need a Screen section to tie the both Device sections together:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidiaScreen"
    Device "DiscreteNvidia" # put the actual Identifier of your Nvidia GPU Device section here
    GPUDevice "IntegratedIntel"
EndSection
```

This tells the Xorg X11 server that while it should use the Nvidia GPU as the primary one, it should also load the driver for the Intel GPU as you will be wanting to do something with it too.

Assuming that you have the appropriate X.org driver packages installed, you should now get to the point where `xrandr --listproviders` will show two providers. Then, the `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0` (i.e. "let *outputs* of provider 1 use provider 0 as the *source*) command should establish the connection between the two GPUs. If successful, `xrandr` with no parameters should display the connectors and displays connected to them for both GPUs.

Then it'll be just a matter of specifying what you'll want to do with the second display: is it going to duplicate what the first display shows (e.g. for presentations) or if it is going to be used to extend the desktop, and if the latter, where is the second display located physically relative to the first one.